# AlamoFire does not compile for OSX project

Tags: macos, swift, alamofire

I upgraded an existing OSX project to using Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

I added `AlamoFire.swift` directly into my project. I get this compile error.

[image]

I imported the same file to a new OSX project and the project compiles fine.

Any ideas on why it is failing?

Comment: did you also update alamofire?

Comment: @Simon What do you mean by update? I cloned a local copy of AlamoFire, then dragged the `AlamoFire.swift` file into my project.

Comment: You updated the project, and my question was; did you also get a fresh copy of alamofire? Maybe it was built for swift 1.1 or so.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Xcode which should have the latest version of Swift as well. Xcode suggesting to add brackets for `$1.value` is not correct because `value` is just a property on `NSHTTPCookie`